# Incorrect range width when importing CSV data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, csv-import

I am using a Google Apps Script to import CSV data. All the CSV data gets imported but this error message still appears:

> Incorrect range width, was 1 but should be 5

My CSV file is separated using `';'` and has commas in there, too. Example from my CSV file:

```
FJ32-19A354-AA;'BES_301 - Exterior Trim;'000101;BOM No CAD;04/01/16
```

There are 5 columns in total and when I state the number of columns in the `getRange()` call, I get another error:

> Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,number,number)

Example code I'm currently using (adapted from ["Ask Ben"](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-Ask-Ben-Parsing-CSV-Strings-With-Javascript-Exec-Regular-Expression-Command.htm)):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1V8YG8lyNZiTllEPHENcnabYRLDPCK6mHGUyAyNhW0Is'); // data_sheet_id = id of spreadsheet that holds the data to be updated with new report data
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); // see below for CSVToArray function
var lastrow = s.getLastRow(); 
  s.getRange(lastrow+ 1, 1,5, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ){

    strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ";");


    var objPattern = new RegExp(
        (
            // Delimiters.
            "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

            // Quoted fields.
            "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

            // Standard fields.
            "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
        ),
        "gi"
        );


    var arrData = [[]];

    var arrMatches = null;

    while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

        // Get the delimiter that was found.
        var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

        // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
        // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
        // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
        // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
        if (
            strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
            strMatchedDelimiter !== strDelimiter
            ){

            // Since we have reached a new row of data,
            // add an empty row to our data array.
            arrData.push( [] );

        }

        var strMatchedValue;

        // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
        // let's check to see which kind of value we
        // captured (quoted or unquoted).
        if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

            // We found a quoted value. When we capture
            // this value, unescape any double quotes.
            strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
                new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
                "\""
                );

        } else {

            // We found a non-quoted value.
            strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

        }

        // Now that we have our value string, let's add
        // it to the data array.
        arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
    }

    // Return the parsed data.
    return( arrData );
}
```

Comment: I think you need to include more code. What does `CSVToArray` do, and what is `s`?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Mogsdad can you help with this as well please?

Answer (score 2):

The error is coming from this line of code:

```
s.getRange(lastrow+ 1, 1,5, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
```

You have 5 values inside the parenthesis.  `getRange()` takes 4 parameters at the most.

```
.getRange(start Row, start Column, Number of Rows, Number of Columns)
```

Remove either the number `5`, or `csvData.length`.

Currently, `csvData.length` is probably being used for the "number of columns" setting, instead of `csvData[0].length`.

When I run the `CSVToArray()` function with your example data, I get a two dimensional array of:

```
[["FJ32-19A354-AA", "'BES_301 - Exterior Trim", "'000101", "BOM No CAD", "04/01/16"]]
```

When I log the length:

```
Logger.log('arrData[0].length: ' + arrData[0].length);
```

It returns the correct length of 5.  So, it looks like the `CSVToArray()` function is working correctly, for the data example you provided.

Right now, you have the number `5` in the place where the `number of rows` should be.  But there is only one inner array in the outer array.  That would make sense of the error message.  The code "thinks" there should be 5 rows, but there is only one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have made the changes but i am still getting the errors  `ss.getRange(lastrow + 1, 1,csvData.length,csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);` and if i remove `csvData.length` i get incorrect height error

Comment: Incorrect range width, was 1 but should be 5 (line 18, file "Code")       Error with the following code: `ss.getRange(lastrow + 1, 1,csvData.length,csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);`

Comment: Is that with the sample data?

Comment: yes it is, there are in total 8127 rows with data similar to that all with data in 5 columns

Comment: In the `while` loop of the `CSVToArray()` function, check every loop for the length of *that* row of data.  If only one of the 8127 rows is a different dimension than all the other rows, you will get an error.  If 8,126 rows are all perfect, and just one of them has an inner loop length that isn't equal to 5, then there will be an error.

Comment: i have checked the rows and all of them have 5 columns.

Comment: I have no idea what the error is being produced by.  At this point, I don't see why you should be having the error.  Maybe if you use the debugger and step through the code line by line for a few iterations, you'll see something wrong.  [Google Documentation - Debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Comment: i have gone through the debugger they all seem to have 5 columns in there... i can only see 99 rows, i cannot see any other logs

Comment: Well, the *only* possibility, is that somewhere in the data, there is an inner array that does not have 5 elements.  There is no other possibility.  You have the `setValues()` parameters set correctly with `ss.getRange(lastrow + 1, 1,csvData.length,csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);`  Unless your `csvData` array is not a two dimensional array.  Those are the only two possibilities.  When the `CSVToArray` function is running, add some code that double checks the inner array before pushing it into the outer array.

Comment: I am very new to google script or javascript so I do not know how to check inner arrays.  I have however ran some logs to check.  Checking the log for `arrData[0].length` i get  arrData[0].length: 5
  arrData[0].length: 5  
  arrData[0].length: 5  
  arrData[0].length: 5   i could only get 5000 log lines as it was too large to complete the run. the second log i ran `Logger.log('csvData[0].length`  i got  csvData[0].length: 5 csvData.length:8127.  so i am lost

Comment: An update, i decided to separate the CSV files to 9 files containing approx 1000 rows each and processed them each separately and they all went fine without errors...

Comment: there seems to be a limit on how many rows that `getrange()` can run at a time. the limit i think is around 3000. Is there any way that i can make the code do 3000 at a time without manually splitting the CSV file.

Comment: Okay, very interesting, and I'm glad you figured that out.  There is a way to run code up to a "certain point", quit, and then start running again without an interruption.  That would probably be a good question to ask.  Maybe ask a new question.  This is turning into a situation where you need multiple answers.

Comment: ok, i have asked the new question, hopefully i will get this resolved. It has been ongoing for a long time now. thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

When importing CSV file rows will vary in length, which will cause this error.
You need to make sure all rows are of the same size

First you need a function to resize rows, copied from another stackoverflow topic:

```
function resize(array, newSize, defaultValue) {
    while(newSize > array.length)
        array.push(defaultValue);
    array.length = newSize;
}
```

Then you can import:

```
function readCSV(sheet, data) {

  var table = [];
  var lines = data.split("\n");
  var maxCol = 0;
  for (var l = 0; l < lines.length; ++l) {
    var line = lines[l];
    var cells = line.split(",");
    table.push(cells);

    if (maxCol < cells.length)
      maxCol = cells.length;
  }

  // Important!
  // resize all rows to be of the same column number, otherwise setValues will fail!
  for (var i = 0; i < table.length; ++i)
    resize(table[i], maxCol, '');


  sheet.getRange(1, 1, table.length, table[0].length).setValues(table);


  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Comment: Logged in to post this very question and answer it because it has foiled me twice now, and I always forget that short rows will cause this width error.  Thx for posting.